# ReactJS: Calculate average from array of strings in JSON object during render

Tags: json, reactjs

**My First Application with ReactJS**

I have no prior experience with `reactjs` and `json`, but am trying to increase my skill set and have been told `reactjs` is great for front end.

I am attempting to read an call an `API`, get a `json` object, parse it and display certain information. I am able to achieve almost all of this with relative ease with the help of several online tutorials, but I have hit a wall.

**Issue**:
I have parsed and displayed the majority of the `json` object but there is an `array` of strings in each object. I would like to take the average of that `array` from the `json` object and display that in `html` as well. Below is my attempt:

```js
//importing necessary modules
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//class creates the React component I am building
class ContentFeed extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();

     this.state = {
       'workers': []
     }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     this.getItems();
   }

   getItems() {
     fetch('localhost:7575')
       .then(results => results.json())
       //.then(results => console.log(results));
       .then(results => this.setState({'workers': results.workers}));
   }

   render() {
     return (            
       <ul>
         // I'm quite new to reactjs 
         // so I'm not too sure if what I'm doing below is legal syntax
         {this.state.workers.map(function(item, index) {
             var arrNum = 0;    
             var h = item.hours.split(",");
             var sum = 0;
             for(var i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(h[i]);
             }
             arrNum = (sum/h.length);    
             return (
                <div key={index}>
                  <h1>{item.firstName} {item.lastName}</h1>
                  <h4>{item.hireDate}</h4>
                  <h4>{item.dept}</h4>
                  <h4>arrNum</h4>
                </div>
              )
          })}
       </ul>
     );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ContentFeed/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What should appear is an `html` page with a header that contains the employees name followed by smaller headers containing the relevant employee info followed by an avg of their work hours.

However the webpage is blank.

I have checked the `console` tab in the developer's tools on the page and have seen an error like this:

```sh
Uncaught TypeError: item.hours.split is not a function
    at index.js:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ContentFeed.render (index.js:26)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17160)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17110)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18620)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
```

I am unsure how to resolve this. I sincerely hope I have provided as much relevant information as needed. Thank you for any help.

**UPDATE 1**

This is from the console tab

```
Uncaught TypeError: item.hours.split is not a function
    at index.js:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ContentFeed.render (index.js:26)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17160)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17110)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18620)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is some of the raw JSON from fetch

```
{
"workers": [
{
"firstName": "Tom",
"lastName": "Ronson",
"dept": "Sales",
"hireDate": "09/09/2015",
"hours": [
"8",
"10",
"4",
"6",
"6"
]
},
{
"firstName": "Bob",
"lastName": "Howser",
"dept": "Acct",
"hireDate": "01/05/2005",
"hours": [
"8",
"10",
"4",
"6",
"6"
]
},
{
"firstName": "Jane",
"lastName": "Winger",
"dept": "Legal",
"hireDate": "08/01/2008",
"hours": [
"5",
"6",
"5",
"5",
"6"
]
},
```

Comment: are you sure about the data you're receiving from the server?

Comment: yes, I have checked it with console log and then I have also seen the plain json with a chrome plugin.

Comment: Can you update question with example response data? And if also possible, duplicate this code into a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with some sample test state? Also, according to your snippet it would be `item.hours.split(...` versus `items.hours.split(...`, there's an 's' in the bit about the TypeError.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand, do you want a screen shot of what happens when I run the code? apologies for the typo.

Comment: No, copy/paste of the response into your question is preferable. Plain text is required over screencaps of code.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, but can you also update your question with the response data you get from the `fetch` request?

Comment: I am so sorry I am not exactly sure what you are asking for. I understand that fetch is going to the the url and .then functions capture the json and store it. But I'm not sure where I could find those results as mywebpage just comes back blank.

Comment: I thought you'd said you'd checked it with console log and seen the plain JSON in a chrome plugin. You can also get it from the network tab in the chrome dev tools (F12), and if you have the react-dev-tools extension installed you can examine your component's state and props.

Comment: ok apologies, I think I understand what you are asking for. I'll post some of that json now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your response data's `hours` property is an array of strings, not a comma separated list of hours as a string.

```
workers: [
  {
    firstName: "Tom",
    lastName: "Ronson",
    dept: "Sales",
    hireDate: "09/09/2015",
    hours: ["8", "10", "4", "6", "6"]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Howser",
    dept: "Acct",
    hireDate: "01/05/2005",
    hours: ["8", "10", "4", "6", "6"]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Jane",
    lastName: "Winger",
    dept: "Legal",
    hireDate: "08/01/2008",
    hours: ["5", "6", "5", "5", "6"]
  }
]
```

The average hours worked can be computed using an array::reduce to compute a sum of hours divided by the array length

```
const avg =
    item.hours.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + Number(curr), 0) /
    item.hours.length;
```

You can map the data as such (*don't forget to use correct JSX syntax, i.e. `<h4>{avg}</h4>` versus `<h4>avg</h4>`*)

```
{this.state.workers.map((item, index) => {
  const avg =
    item.hours.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + Number(curr), 0) /
    item.hours.length;

  return (
    <li key={index}>
      <h1>
        {item.firstName} {item.lastName}
      </h1>
      <h4>{item.hireDate}</h4>
      <h4>{item.dept}</h4>
      <h4>{avg}</h4> // <-- * use correct JSX syntax
    </li>
  );
})}
```

[image: Edit reactjs-calculate-average-from-array-of-strings-in-json-object-during-render]

Answer (score 1):

> there is an array of strings in each JSON object. I would like to take the average of that array

From your description, `item.hours` is an array of strings. But in your code

> `item.hours.split(",");`

You treat it like a single, comma-separated, string.

Given you're getting TypeError, it seems it is in fact an array of strings (preferably you'd update your question with sample data).

To get the average of an array, you can use `reduce`:

```js
  const avg = item.hours.reduce((a,b) => a + parseFloat(b),0) / item.hours.length;
```